# MVC Set view render/execution order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, action

Is it possible to set the order of execution of the rendered views?

Let's say I have a view which is rendered in a layout but it needs to be rendered LAST, after all other views. (But it is not on the bottom of the layout)

> Layout

```
<html>
    <body>
        ...
        @Html.Action("Index", "Test1")
        @Html.Action("Index", "Test2")
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

> Controllers

```
public class Test1Controller: Controller
{
    private readonly PassedAround _passedAround;

    public Test1Controller(PassedAround passedAround){
        _passedAround = passedAround;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(){
        return View(_passedAround);
    }
}

public class Test2Controller: Controller
{
    private readonly PassedAround _passedAround;

    public Test1Controller(PassedAround passedAround){
        _passedAround = passedAround;
    }

    public ActionResult Index(){
        _passedAround.Whatever = 1;
        return View();
    }
}
```

> View (Test1Controller - Index)

```
...
@Html.Raw(Model.Whatever)
...
```

In the example above, the value of PassedAround.Whatever is set AFTER the Test1Controller-Index is rendered.

Comment: Seems like a case of the [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), as your question still doesn't seem very logical (to me) .... What are you trying to accomplish? Can you share your layout and what you're wanting to do with it?

Comment: It is not logical. The client asked me to pass around an object, during the request and "sometimes" to change it according to the (partial) controller we're in. After all controllers are executed, this last view should be rendered, depending on all previous controllers. Not my idea to do it like this... But I just need to know if it is possible... and if so, how.

Comment: You'll really need to include some example code for anyone to understand what you mean. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You do not render controllers, but rather views in MVC. Also the concept of masterpage refers to a Layout view in MVC which is within the shared folder. Your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted. I agree with you; as the question was originally posed, you gave a good answer. It seems the author of the question may be confusing WebForms concepts with MVC concepts or is using a mixed environment which would be relevant to include in the question.